# Are custom data values on PDAs publicly viewable by anybody?

Tags: pda, explorers

Are the custom values that I set on a PDA viewable by anyone.
For example: If I create a PDA with values..

```
#[account]
pub struct Item {
    pub secret: String,
    pub passwords: String
}
```

Are these values viewable by anyone that knows the PDA address?
Is it discoverable through an explorer like SolanaFM, Solscan, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A blockchain is a public ledger. All data provided on a blockchain are publicly viewable to anyone looking at each account. While not all data on accounts are serialized the same way, the data itself should be treated as public data.

It is recommended to not store passwords or secrets on a blockchain. Treat everything as public.

Comment: Got it. Follow up scenario, if the created PDA is deleted. Will the data still be available to view either currently or somehow viewing past data?

Comment: Yes, the data will be available

Comment: I received a somewhat contradictory answer here for a similar but slightly different scenario. 
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8841/does-solana-log-changes-to-data-on-a-program-account/

Can you confirm this is not what you believe is true?